# iOS Shortcut, regex match these words, while excluding these words

Tags: shortcuts-app

I am using iOS Shortcuts and am using it get contents of page (converts the page to RTF), then running through make text to turn it into plain text.

I am trying to develop an IUC flavored regex to search for key words/phrases on a list of pages I am looping over with a while each, but want the regular expression to exclude other phrases and prevent a false-positive trigger.

I have it set up with two capture groups. I'm not sure if it is desired to make the second group a non-capture group, or not attempt capture at all. I only think the second one must be either a capture, or non-capture group for the logical AND provided. I read that (this)(that) acts as an and, but I'm not sure if either is a negate, whether it follows that logic. For that reason, I'm not sure if the negate should not be it's own capture group, non-capture group, or shouldn't be using the brackets at all. I had tried some nested capture group stuff, but that seems to not follow the syntax.

Currently, I have tried a wide variety of regular expressions. I do not have a full list, but I can share a few permutations I have tried starting with the most recent:

```
(?>Include\sTerm\sOne|Include\sTerm\sTwo|Include\sTerm\s3)(?:<!Exclude\sTerm\sOne|Exclude\sTerm\sTwo|Exclude\sTerm\s3)

(?Include\sTerm\sOne|Include\sTerm\sTwo|Include\sTerm\s3)^(?!Exclude\sTerm\sOne|Exclude\sTerm\sTwo|Exclude\sTerm\s3)
```

Just to be clear, I want it to first search the exclude terms and fail if it finds one. Then if it doesn't find any of these negate terms, then begin searching through the include terms. It is fine that the include list and exclude list terms, respective to each grouping are being treated on an OR basis (per piping |) as that is the intended behavior I'm seeking. Finally, I am wanting to start my search at the top of the page and for it to stop searching / attempting capture in this logical order:

- Exclude term found, STOP
  -- First include term found, STOP

Final note, this search is obviously performed over multiple lines. I am only seeking to capture the include term, not the exclude term. I only want the exclude term to cancel out a match of both exist (either before or after - cross directionally). That is if an exclude term exists, negate the positive term and provide zero matches.

Comment: At its heart, this question is about regular expressions not Apple stuff.

Comment: I think this misunderstands what a regular expression does; [it is not a program](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/426851/11948). Grouping modifiers do not work like operators in a programming language. For instance, `(?>…)` is a possessive match, which influences backtracking, but doesn’t define some kind of programmatic logic. Negative lookaheads `(?!…)` make sure your match is not immediately followed by something else (e.g. “apostrophe not followed by s”); again, not a programmatic logic. Negation `^` only works inside character classes. `(?…)` and `(?:<!…)` are not a thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is not program, it is just a very complex search pattern. In a nutshell, the only thing a regular expression can do is either match or not match, returning the first match it finds (including related sub matches, as may be) in the former case, or nothing in the latter.

That means that to implement a conditional “accept or reject” logic where both branches are predicated on matches, a regular expression is the wrong tool. Instead, that implementation needs to be done **programmatically**, leveraging regular expressions step for step:

1. First search for a regular expression of exclude terms (e.g. `(No|Neither|…|Nope)`). If that returns a match, skip the document and move on to the next.
2. Then search for a regular expression of include terms (e.g. `(Yes|Please|…|Thanks)`). If that returns a match, process the document, else skip the document and move on to the next.